# Form Request, how to add additional error messages after performing a validation using an if- condition?

Tags: laravel, validation

Adding error messages inside form requests using certain conditions.

I am making a form request in order to handle my validations. In my form, I have a couple of fields but the important ones are "Month" "Day" or "Year" pulldown. They are all set to required, and if one of them invalidates the required rule, the form request would handle it by creating another error inside the $validator.

The logic goes something like this.

```
If (month = fail || day = fail || year = fail) {
   $validator->errors()->add('date', 'please fill out the whole date)
}
```

I'd like to do this somewhere in my form request after the validation.

This is my rules for the form request field.

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'nullable',
            'sex' => 'nullable',
            'phone_number' => 'nullable',
            'email' => 'nullable',
            'month' => 'bail|required',
            'day' => 'bail|required',
            'year' => 'bail|required',
        ];
    }
```

And on my view (twig template) under the select fields of month, day, year, I have this to supposedly show my error message:

```
{{errors.first('date')}}
```

So far I don't know how to write the condition and add a custom error message.

Edit: I found an answer, but I'm not sure if this is good practice. Maybe someone can find a better answer than this.

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator) {

        if (array_key_exists('month', $validator->failed()) || 
            array_key_exists('day', $validator->failed()) ||
            array_key_exists('year', $validator->failed()) ) {
                $validator->getMessageBag()->add('date', 'sample error message');
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be best to use an **After Validation Hook**.

You would typically add this to your Form Request.

```
/**
* Configure the validator instance.
*
* @param  \Illuminate\Validation\Validator  $validator
* @return void
*/
public function withValidator($validator)
{
    $validator->after(function ($validator) {
        if(
            $validator->errors()->has('month')
            || $validator->errors()->has('day')
            || $validator->errors()->has('year')
        ) {
            $validator->errors()->add('date', 'Please fill out the whole date!');
        }
    });
}
```

You can check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#form-request-validation) for more information.

Comment: Could I ask in addition what the difference is between using withValidator($validator) + after validation hook vs failedValidation($validator) in terms of handling errors inside form request, seeing that both can call the validator instance. https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.html indicates that failedValidation($validator) method is for handling failed validation requests. I was just curious if there are any major differences, pros or cons with these methods.

Comment: In your particular case, there's no major difference since you want to know when the Validator fails anyway. However, in the case of an After Validation Hook, you are *adding* more responsibilities to the Validator before it is actually *evaluated*

Comment: Cheers for helping me out friend! :)

Comment: Regarding the code above ('ignoring the if statement'), I thought that adding errors to the error bag manually using `$validator->errors()->add()` would throw an exception and fail the validation.